# SFDX Source Push: Invalid type: FeedItem

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, feeditem

I am getting error:

> Invalid type: FeedItem

When I run command:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

Why won't it let me push that code into my scratch org?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to enable `Chatter` in my `Scratch Org`

```
Setup > Chatter > Chatter Settings > Edit > Enable
```